# How do I say "Actually" In the context of "You don't ACTUALLY have to do that"

Tags: phrases

Would like to know which correct word to use in that context & how would I say the aforementioned sentence in Japanese! My best guess would be to use 本当 ?

Comment: Is *actually* used for emphasizing the whole *you don't have to do that* or meaning, say, *you don't have to do that, but you have to understand/know/think how to do it etc.*?

Comment: How would you use 本当 in a complete sentence?

Comment: @sundowner The latter! Like maybe i'm watching a video with someone and in the video someone tells the viewer to open their mouth, and i see my friend open their mouth so I am amused and tell them "You don't ACTUALLY have to open your mouth" Something like that! Sorry for the weird example !

Comment: @aguijonazo Maybe 本当にそれをする必要がない ? Uh i'm not sure, on second thought it sounds wrong, as if I am trying to say "You really don't have to do that" which isn't quite what i'm looking for ahhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

本当に is not bad. You could say:

> 本当にする必要**は**ない。

> 本当にしなくて（も）いい。

それを would sound redundant and should be removed. If する alone doesn’t make it clear what the other person doesn’t have to do, then you should use a more specific verb.

> 本当に口を開ける必要はない。

> 本当に口を開けなくて（も）いい。

If you need to eliminate the risk of 本当に being understood as “really,” you can replace it with 実際に. It sounds slightly more formal, though.